# RuntimeError: Unable to open shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat?

Tags: python, opencv, cx-freeze

I´ve made a project with python OpenCV, and used the shape_predictor_68... a .dat file.
Now when I build the project with cx_freeze, everything does right, but when I run the app build, it shows a error.

[image]

Comment: no, still trying, nothing wrong with libraries... already tried to re-write the code in a diferent environment... nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also facing the same issue but after some search, I get to  know my shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat is not updated or correct so I replace it with another and issue resolved, the link for the new shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat file is
https://github.com/AKSHAYUBHAT/TensorFace/blob/master/openface/models/dlib/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat

replace the new file with older one.

Comment: the link is no longer valid

Comment: the git link is of someone's personal account maybe he/she removed that file from the git

Comment: @HarshvardhanR Go to http://dlib.net/files/ and click 'shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2' 

I could have provided the link to it directly but it didnt download when redirected from websites.

Answer (score 0):

Referring the solution to a [similar issue here](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/issues/76)

If you are getting this error:

> RuntimeError: Unable to open /home/lyz/openface-master/demos/web/../../models/dlib/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat

You probably haven't downloaded dlibs models properly, perform Step 4 from https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/setup/ again. In short, cd into your openface library and run
`./models/get-models.sh`

Also, I can't tell how you are running this but it could also be a case that the library may not be correctly imported in your current `venv` - where your interpreter is.

Answer (score 0):

Install dlib correctly and just paste this .dat file in the same working directory as your code is present and try to run the code.

The link is
http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2

You can find the .dat file here after extracting a WinZip file that can be downloaded from the dlib.net website.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue, download the dat file from this link and paste it in your project folder,

http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34956909)